# Prove that the set of rational numbers is disconnected as a subset of the Real Numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Definition of open: Let E ⊂ S and let F ⊂ E. Then F is said to be
open in E if and only if there is an open set O ⊂ S such that F = E∩O.

Definition of disconnected: A set E ⊂ S is said to be disconnected if and only
if there are disjoint, nonempty subsets A and B of E that are open in E
and such that E = A∪B. A set in S is said to be connected if and only
if it is not disconnected.

I am struggling with trying to prove this, and was hoping someone could provide a step by step on how to approach this problem. Thanks!

EDIT: I understand that the set of rational numbers can be shown as the union of the set {x: x^2 > 2} and {x: x^2 < 2}, but how do you show that these sets are open in the set of rationals?

Comment: Think about $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider  $(-\infty, r)$ and $(r, \infty) $ as candidates...  where $r$ is chosen appropriately...

Comment: @Przemyslaw I understand this part, but more specifically how should I go about showing that these two sets are open in the set of rational numbers.

Comment: @a.nas They are open in the natural topology of reals, so also open in the subspace with induced topology.

Comment: @Przemyslaw In the proof I want to include the use of the definition of open that I provided. Is there anyway to do that? Even if they are open in the natural topology of reals, I still want to be able to show they are open using the definition of open.

Comment: @a.nas Your definition is exactly the definition of an open set in a topology of a subspace.